# subset vertices such that minimum weight is d

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

Imagine you have a weighted undirected graph G=(V,E) that is fully connected (edge between every pair of vertices). You seek to have a graph G' where G' is a subset of G where vertices with their corresponding edges have been removed such that the edge with the minimum weight is d.

Trivially you can just remove all vertices but a few with highly weighted edges. But what if you want G' to be as big as possible ?   What is the way to remove the minimal set of vertices to satisfy the weight condition ?

For instance I have graph A,B,C  (A,B) = 2 (A,C) = 3 and (B,C) = 2 and my minimum d=2. I could remove both A and C to get just B. But I could also remove B to leave A and C. The second solution is the one with the minimal amount of removals.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

Comment: The vertex cover of a fully connected graph is a single vertex.

Comment: The instance of vertex cover is not fully connected.

Comment: The result has to be fully connected. If you remove vertices from a fully connected graph, the result will be fully connected as well.

Comment: The problems are trivially interreducible. I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: 1) This is not my homework. 2) If it were, a vertex cover is "a set of vertices such that each edge of the graph is incident to at least one vertex of the set." which is for a fully connected any vertex you like.

Comment: @user2525190 I suspect David means that you run vertex cover on a graph where you have deleted all edges of weight d or higher.  The vertices in the minimum vertex cover are the ones you need to remove.

Comment: oh no ! You cannot remove the edges. You can only remove the vertices, the edges are removed automatically.